# Remover Scroll de menu responsivo

Tags: javascript, html, css

gostaria de ajuda para uma duvida de iniciante.

Fiz um menu responsivo do tipo hambuguer e gostaria de travar o scroll para quando ele estiver aberto não ter como rolar a tela.

```css
.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 18px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.1rem 0.5rem #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--ame);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5rem;
}

.navigation ul li a {
  color: var(--white);
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.navigation ul li a:hover {
  color: var(--yellow);
}

.menu {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  /*esta escondendo o menu bar*/
}

.menu .bar {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: var(--yellow);
  margin: 5px auto;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  @media (max-width: 810px) {
    .navigation {
      padding: 18px 20px;
    }
    .navigation ul {
      padding-top: 80px;
      gap: 0;
    }
    .navigation ul li a {
      color: var(--white);
      font-size: 1rem;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 10px;
      transform: translateX(100%)
    }
    .menu {
      display: block;
    }
    .menu.ativo .bar:nth-child(1) {
      transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    .menu.ativo .bar:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    .menu.ativo .bar:nth-child(3) {
      transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    .nav-menu {
      position: absolute;
      right: -100vh;
      top: 70px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      flex-direction: column;
      background: var(--ame);
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
    .nav-menu.ativo {
      right: 0;
    }
    .nav-item {
      margin: 16px 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<nav class="navigation">
  <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">API Docs</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Ferramentas</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Entrar</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Cadastrar</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="menu">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -3):

Pode ser que usar o overflow resolva o seu problema

```
body {
      overflow: hidden;
}
```

Essa tag tem outras propriedades que possam ser a solução do seu problema, você pode ler um pouco mais sobre ela nesse [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Eu estava tentando desde cedo fazer comele,porém termina travando não só o menu, ele trava o scroll na aplicação toda mesmo com o menu fechado.